# Django Pattern: Celery + Async + Model Writing

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I need to access multiple websites at once and save their data. I'm aware that Django isn't async and that models can't be accessed asynchronously.

So what's an architecture I can use to achieve this? I'm using await `asyncio.gather()` to make the queries but I'm not sure how to get to writing this to the database synchronously. Send it to another task queue? Move it into an array and pop them out one at a time to write synchronously?

Comment: Seems like your post title have the answer: celery or any type of async worker

Comment: @dkarchmer since i can't call synchronous code from asyc code i'm not sure how to do it. any examples would be helpful.

Comment: You don’t need to use any asych code. You simply need a worker that can process a single site and create the database record for it. Then your front end just has to publish a task for each web site and have multiple workers each process one site independently

Comment: @dkarchmer each worker needs to hit multiple (paged) endpoints at once so I'm trying to download them simultaneously so users don't wait an hour for it to finish

Comment: Then you are not explaining well. Why does each worker need to hit multiple pages at once? Why can this not be parallelized across different workers? Is it that you need all the results before you can write to the database?

Comment: @dkarchmer I am already using Celery, but each worker needs to hit multiple pages at once because there is a very large amount of data they're syncing, possibly in the tens-of-thousand+ json objects from an API. this is for a service where a user is syncing their social data, so right now downloading that data (in Celery) takes roughly 2 hours for an account with 20,000 objects because the API forces it to be split into 100-object chunks. I need to query all 20k as concurrently as possible, but Django doesn't handle async/await and we're not supposed to access models from async code

Comment: Too open ended of a question but I would have the main celery task schedule the 100 additional task for each to download a chunk and put it on a database ( preliminary model if need to be ) and use Redis or equivalent to coordinate everybody. Basically create your own Redis based semaphore system. Don’t know about the specifics but the API either tells you I advanced how many total objects you are going to need or you can schedule say ten jobs at a time and have those jobs schedule more until one jobs cannot get any more data d sets Redis to stop